# How to use "other" as a wildcard language in django translations

Tags: django, django-cms, django-i18n

I am building a website in django-cms which will support mainly 2 languages (en, es).

However, "guest" articles will appear at times in many more languages (like 15 or more potentially). I do not want to add all of these separately. I would rather use something like (en, es, "other") as a wildcard to hold all languages other than the 2 main ones.

The reason is to keep the CMS as simple as possible as these entries will be quite rare. Also, I don't know beforehand which languages might be used so I can't add them statically in the settings.py file.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do that & it wouldn't work if you could. Just add the languages when you know what you are going to support.

The purpose of including a language is that you write content in that language for the people who use that particular language. You can't write content in `other`, so just stick to the languages you'll actually have content written in.

Comment: Thanks. For my use-case it would make little sense to add all 15 languages though. Especially statically in the settings file. I ended up creating another django model for these guest articles which the language info is just stored as a tag...

Comment: But that's just how localisation works in Django. It needs those static languages in your settings.

Comment: Found a (not semantically correct) hack around this issue: to pick a very rare language code. In my case I went for 'na' (Nauru) and renamed it in my settings file: `LANGUAGES = [("en", _("English")),("es", _("Spanish")),("an", _("Other")),]`. That way content editors can put all content for languages other than the main ones under "Other"